# Go: type []string has no field or method len

Tags: go

I am trying to compile the following function:

```
func (self algo_t) chk_args(args []string) {
    if args.len() != self.num_args {
        fmt.Fprintf(
            os.Stdout,
            "%s expected %d argument(s), received %d\n",
            self.name,
            self.num_args,
            args.len(),
        )
        fmt.Printf("quickcrypt %s\n", self.usage)
    }
}
```

I am receiving the error, `args.len undefined (type []string has no field or method len)`.

Args is of type `[]string`, and the language specification [says](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) this is a slice type. The `builtin` package documentation [says](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#len) `v.len()` is defined for Slice types. What is going on?

Comment: The documentnation says len(v) is defined, not v.len(). len is not a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
func (self *algo_t) chk_args(args []string) {
    if len(args) != self.num_args {
        fmt.Fprintf(
            os.Stdout,
            "%s expected %d argument(s), received %d\n",
            self.name,
            self.num_args,
            len(args),
        )
        fmt.Printf("quickcrypt %s\n", self.usage)
    }
}
```

`func len(v Type) int` is a built in function that allows you to pass in a variable, not a built in function on a type.

As a side note, you probably want chk_args to be a function on a pointer to algo_t like I have in the example.

Answer (score 8):

`len` isn't a method, it's a function. That is, use `len(v)` and not `v.len()`

Comment: One thing to be careful about is that the `len` function will return the allocated size, not the populated size: http://play.golang.org/p/-V7W0Scn_6

Comment: @dethtron5000 No, the allocated size is returned by `cap`.